# Proving that an operator that commutes with any other operator defined on a euclidean space is an homothecy

Tags: operator-theory, homothety

I need to show that if $A$ is an operator defined on a euclidean space so that it commutes with every other operator $B$ defined on the same euclidean space, then $A=\lambda I$.

**Attempt at a solution**

If $[A,B]=0$ for every operator on $E$ (euclidean space) then, in particular, $[A,P_x]=0$, where $P_x$ is a projector operator on $x\in E$ define as:
$$P_x y = \frac{x(x,y)}{||x||^2}$$

Then, given an element $y\in E$ we can calculate $[A,P_x]y=0$:
$$AP_x y = P_x Ay$$
$$AP_x y = \frac{x(x,Ay)}{||x||^2}$$
$$Ax = \frac{(x,Ay)}{||x||^2}x$$

What we have calculated above gives a explicit expression for $\lambda$. But, this quantity $\frac{(x,Ay)}{||x||^2}$ is dependent , in principle, on $y\in E$.

Nevertheless, we can show that $\lambda_x$ is independent of the choice of $x,y$. Taking two L.I vectors on $E$ $u,v$ we want to show the independence of $\lambda_x$:

Is evident that $Ax = \lambda_x x$ for every $x\in E$, so in particular ,
$$A(u+v)=\lambda_{u+v}(u+v)$$
Using the linearity of $A$:
$$Au+Av=\lambda_{u+v}(u+v)$$
$$\lambda_u u+\lambda_v v=\lambda_{u+v}(u+v)$$
$$(\lambda_{u+v}-\lambda_u)u+(\lambda_{u+v}-\lambda_v)v=0$$
Because of $u,v$ are L.I then $\lambda_{u+v}-\lambda_u=0 \ \wedge \ \lambda_{u+v}-\lambda_v=0$. This implies $\lambda_u = \lambda_v$. This also holds in the case $u,v$ are not L.I. Consider $u=\alpha v$ then $Au=\alpha Au$, this implies $\lambda_u u=\alpha \lambda_v v=\lambda_v u$, then $\lambda_u=\lambda_v$.

This completes the proof.

My question is: Is there a proof that treats the general case for $A$ and $B$ arbitrary?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't $A$ arbitrary?

Comment: You're right. I mean just $B$ arbitrary.

Comment: There is another proof, which is quite similar in spirit but uses components. Take the basis $E_{ij}$ of elementary matrices ($1$ in one position). Then $AE=EA$ gives the result.

Comment: But I think this would imply that the space $E$ is finite dimensional. I think this should hold even for infinite dimensional space

Comment: Absolutely right. You mentioned Euclidean space, so I thought it was finite dimensional.

Comment: I thought a bit more about this. The proof works even for infinite dimensions. Pick any two dimensional subspace $V$ in the vector space $E$. Then the fact that $A$ commutes with the elementary matrices of $V$ shows that $A$ is diagonal in $V$ and hence for all $E$. But I still think the proof is essentially the same as yours, except it would work even for Banach spaces.